# Site not redirecting to https even after having rewrite condition

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am working on [this](http://www.demacmedia.com) site which which redirects to https except of when someone writes a url starting with www and opens a page except of homepage. For example,

```
www.demacmedia.com/work
```

Here is the code I am using in htacess file to redirect,

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# Rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont use any htaccess code for apache to redirect wordpress site to https.

Just change the wordpress site url in general settings

and take a look on [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) which is great